# How can I make my splash screen to portrait mode only in iOS phonegap?

Tags: ios, cordova

I have been trying to develop a phonegap application. I have successfully added Splash screen to the application. Problem is, the client wants the application in landscape and portrait mode both but the Splash Screen to portrait mode only. I have already customized the info.plist and successfully make the application useful for both portrait and landscape mode,but I can not set the splash screen to portrait mode only. Can anyone please help?

Comment: I was unable to write a constructive answer — i.e. one that wasn't 90% about how awful PhoneGap is and 10% about the actual issue — so have decided to constrain myself to a comment. This isn't intended Apple behaviour. I think PhoneGap obstructs any of the means you could use to force it. Apple wants the *launch* screen to be a precached copy of the first piece of UI your app will display, so as to make it appear to launch more quickly. The intention is not for you to supply a *splash* screen. So if you say you support landscape, you need to supply a landscape launch screen.

Comment: well, I do not have any choice as I work for a company that takes the requirement from the company that asks for multiple platform app at once.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Do like the following image for landscape and portrait:

Portrait:

[image]

Lanscape:

[image]

**And it will look on both orientations like in portrait**

Comment: Brother, the problem is still the splash screen rotating. I did something once to stop the splash screen to portrait only but can not find out the solution again. As far as I remember,the change I made is in ios native code.

Answer (score -1):

Use this link for your reference it might help you  [splash screen](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html)